# ios - uicollectionview get notified when cellForItemAtIndexPath finished and cells are positioned

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

In iOS, What event can I register to in order to get notified when a call to  cellForItemAtIndexPath has completed and the collection view's cells are all displayed?

Thank you

Comment: `collectionView:didEndDisplayingCell:forItemAtIndexPath:`? It's a method of `UICollectionViewDelegate`.

Comment: Nope, it's only called when the cell is going away as in removed. I want to get notified when its displayed, not when removed

Comment: @Larme that is used for "Use this method to detect when a cell is removed from a collection view, as opposed to monitoring the view itself to see when it appears or disappears." Not what the OP is asking for

Comment: UICollectionView has no notifications that allow for this to happen, I am not sure what you are asking for, because as you scroll cellForItemAtIndexPath will be called constantly. A collection view's cells are never all displayed. Give us some context.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the menu section of the doc, just read the name of the method.

Comment: Are you adding cells after the initial load? If so you can use the performBatchUpdates:completion: to know when the animation has finished.